# bootstrap vue custom sass compiles but does not change variable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sass

currently I'm trying to override some vue-bootstrap styles, I have my own custom scss file importing my bootstrap and bootstrap vue scss, and I am using it inside main.js, even though my sass compiles I am not seeing any changes in my dev server and I'm at a loss

main.scss (my file) -> trying to change the primary variable to a different color

```
//custom sass
$primary: #0dcaf0;

//bootstrap sass import
@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
// BootstrapVue and its default variables
@import '../node_modules/bootstrap-vue/src/index.scss';
```

App.vue (including sass import here, also for some reason if I dont set lang=scss I get an error where webpack can't read the sass comments and throws an unknown word error)

```
<style lang="scss">
@import '../sass/main.scss';

#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
}

</style>
```

main.js (i've included everything in the file just because I don't know if the order matters)

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'

import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css'
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all.js'
import {BootstrapVue, IconsPlugin} from 'bootstrap-vue'
import styles from '../sass/main.scss';

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
Vue.use(IconsPlugin)
Vue.use(styles)

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'

new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

I've been at this for a bit so I'll try to give a history of what I've tried

I have tried editing the $primary variable in node_modules\bootstrap\scss_variables.scss
I have tried editing the $primary variable in node_modules\bootstrap-vue\node_modules\bootstrap\scss_variables.scss

I have also tried changing the color directly, I have tried removing the !default modifier

versions
bootstrap 4.6.0
sass-loader is 10.2.0

I'm thinking my main.scss needs to specify somehow whether its editing the $primary variable in bootstrap or in bootstrap-vue ..... I'm not sure how I can do this? hoping someone has some insight

many thanks :)

Comment: https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/reference/theming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're still including the base `.css` files from both Bootstrap and BootstrapVue. So they will overwrite anything you define in your SCSS.

So remove those two imports from your `main.js` and it should work.

```js
// remove these from main.js
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'
```

You also have this `Vue.use(styles)` which doesn't make sense, since you should only use `Vue.use` on vue plugins, so you should remove that as well.
Which means you can change your import to`import '../sass/main.scss';`

Whether you import `main.scss` in `main.js` or `App.vue` is up to you. But you should only have one or the other, not both.

Comment: ah I see, thank you for explaining it to me, using this I was able to remove the imports and get it working :)